# java.lang.NullPointerException in Unit Testing spring service class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

In a simple mvc application in spring boot , I want to do unit testing of a class of service layer called LibraryService (interface) and LibraryServiceImpl.

```
public interface LibraryService {

    /*
     * Returns media library object given the library object id.
     */
    public MediaLibraryDetail getLibraryById(ObjectId libraryId);
}
```

Below we see it's implementation

```
@Service
public class LibraryServiceImpl implements LibraryService {

    @Autowired
    private LibraryDAOImpl libDao;


    @Override
    public MediaLibraryDetail getLibraryById(ObjectId libraryId) {
        return libDao.getLibraryById(libraryId);
    }
}
```

We can see it has dependency on a class `MediaLibraryDetail`. Also, `ObjectId` is another class which is type of its parameter `libraryId`.

I want to do unit testing in spring boot for method `getLibraryById()`.

Here's is my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LibraryServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private LibraryDAO libDao = new LibraryDAOImpl();
    @Mock
    private ObjectId libraryId;
    @InjectMocks
    private  LibraryService libraryService =new LibraryServiceImpl();


    @Test
    public void getLibraryByIdTest(){

    MediaLibraryDetail mediaLibraryDetail =new MediaLibraryDetail();
    mediaLibraryDetail.setCollectionName("abc");

    when(libDao.getLibraryById(libraryId)).thenReturn(mediaLibraryDetail);
    assertSame(mediaLibraryDetail,libraryService.getLibraryById(libraryId));

    }
}
```

I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException` on this last line `assertSame(mediaLibraryDetail,libraryService.getLibraryById(libraryId));`

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you use it that way?

```
@Mock
private LibraryDAOImpl libDao;
@Mock
private ObjectId libraryId;
@InjectMocks
private LibraryServiceImpl libraryService;
```

Comment: it fails as it cannot find bean of libraryServiceImpl. Here is the error: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException`: 
Cannot instantiate `@InjectMocks` field named `libraryService`.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.However, I failed because: the type `LibraryService` is an interface. Similarly for `libraryDao`.

Comment: with `Impl` it should

Comment: I read somewhere else that you normally test against an implementation because the interface doesn't deliver something to test.

Comment: But If you see my interface holds the implementation object.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin your interface has no place to inject the mock repository, so the injection never happens and you end up with an NPE on trying to access the repository in your implementation class.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin yes indeed you are right, in my environment I can do both ways (1. using Impl directly without any assignment and 2. the interface plus assignment. so maybe it's a version issue. I do have mockito 1.10.19 with spring boot 1.4.3 in my classpath.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin also, when using the Mock, Spy, etc. annotations, you hand over instantiation to the mocking framework and should NOT do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on KLHauser's answer, I'd replace the @InjectMocks annotation (which isn't needed) with a @Spy annotation.

That way you can check whether method on the Dao/repository actually has been called that you expected to be called:

```
verify(libDay).getLibraryById(libraryId);
```

Comment: You cannot replace `@InjectMocks` with `@Spy`. When I read (http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations) and also try it technically , `@Spy` could replace `@Mock` because it's "somehow" more similar.

Comment: @KLHauser replace may give the wrong impression. I meant it as in replacing in the code, not functionally. InjectMocks in this code does nothing, using Spy in its stead is useful because it does have functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

[Get Rid of @InjectMocks](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/)

Comment: that's only part of the problem